# VSCode: Rename symbol (F2) looks broken

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

For some reason, maybe after the update to 1.50.1, F2 (rename symbol) is not working for me anymore.

With "does not work" I mean the F2 just doesn't do anything. I can still rename files and directories in the tree explorer, but not function names, variables etc.

I use the extension Intelephense for PHP; but even after I disable all extensions, deleted ~/.config/User/Code directory, and install a fresh VSCode F2 does not work.

VSCode Version: 1.50.1, commit d2e414
OS Version: Linux x64 5.4.0-51-generic snap
Node.js: 12.14.1

Steps to Reproduce:

- Open vscode with code
- Set cursor on variable name or function name
- click F2

**Expected**: you can edit the name of the symbol to be renamed

**Actual**: nothing happens, so can not rename the symbol.

*Notes*:

- this used to always work, maybe because I updated to the latest
  version? in the tree explorer I can rename a file or directory, but
  not variables/functions in code.
- I use Intelephense extension. But
  same issue appears after uninstalling all extensions, also tried with
  Code Insiders.
- Checked the developers tool bar, there were no errors
  shown when I pressed F2. Actually nothing was shown; as if the F2 is
  not bound to an action.

== UPDATE ==
I chatted with support of vscode via Github. Nothing worked, but what did work was upgradng from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, and a complete removal of vscode (cache, extensions, etc).

Comment: So if anyone has this also, turns out I had PHP Language Features still enabled. According to PHP Intelephense it has to be switched off.(Why it was switched back on I do not know).

Comment: What exactly did you have to disable @eddy147 ? I'm having the same issue. Also using the most excellent Intelephense.

Comment: Never mind. Got it. As per instructions in VS Code @extensions, you type the following in search: `@builtin php` and disable `PHP Language Features` extension (again), but not the `PHP Language Basics`. Weirdly enough I had to re-enter license key again as well. Now it's back to being perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know that we could do F2 in php in vscode to rename refactor class, function, variables, ... As far as I know, it works only in typescript.

Anyway, I have juste made an extension to do the job. Feel free to check it out
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=st-pham.php-refactor-tool&ssr=false#overview

Comment: Hello Son, I tried it out and it is buggy. Sometimes when I include the new name it will create new variables in places where they shouldn't. Here is the proof: https://imgur.com/a/7XEsUhG

Comment: Hello @assensi, could you tell me more about the version of php that you are working with ? Mine is 7.4, however, I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is 7.4.2. After I wrote the comment I even realized that it randomly changed names of variables on other files. A COMPLETE MESS. I HAD to uninstall it immediately. You should seriously consider removing it from the store until you fix these bugs before you get a lot of low stars.

Comment: I forgot to mention the dependencies of the extension, you need to use PHP Intelephense (if it is not the case). And all the extensions having the same functionalities should be disabled in order to have the best result. Regards.

Comment: I could not reproduce at all the errors that you mentioned. So please, follow the instruction, install the dependency, and try it again. Because it is working perfectly from my part.